# What is the term for the morning wake up gesture?

Tags: word-request, image-identification

What term do we use to describe the gesture that we find when someone wakes up and flexes her arms?

Here is the picture. 
[image: Woman waking up in the morning]

Comment: Stretch (one's arms ((and legs)).

Comment: i always call it a **morning stretch**

Comment: Personally, the term I use is "stretch before whacking alarm clock".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The technical term for this is **pandiculation**

> A stretching and stiffening of the trunk and extremities, as when fatigued and drowsy or on waking, often accompanied by yawning. [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pandiculation)

However, this would not be understood by most speakers, and it would normally be refered to as just stretching.

Comment: ngram suggests it is essentially defunct since the 19th century, even if it was ever widely used.

Comment: Ho hum. No one actually says this but it is amusing.

Comment: I had forgotten all about this word! I _have_ heard it before, but you're right, no one ever uses it. Still, it belongs in this conversation.

Comment: Choosing this answer as rest all like stretching...flexing...relaxing...etc I certainly knew!

Comment: In fact, this was ['word of the day' on MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/pandiculation) recently. Worth listening the clip that **exactly** talks about it!

Answer (score 23):

Are you looking for something more specific than *stretch*?

> [stretch](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stretch)
>   1 :  to extend (one's limbs, one's body, etc.) in a reclining position
>   (M-W)

You could call it a *morning stretch* or a *wake-up stretch*, but I don't how common those are, and either could easily mean a yoga-like stretch intended as light exercise done after waking up.

Comment: In Russian we have a special word for that - **потягушечки**.

Comment: That's interesting. Google returns a lot of kittens!

Comment: You are looking in wrong place https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8

Comment: So, she got up with a *morning stretch* goes well?

Comment: @MaulikV That seems okay. I honestly can't think of a good way to phrase this. I would simply say _she stretched after waking_, _she stretched her arms arfter waking up_, _she got up and stretched her arms out_, or some variation of the those. I'm less inclined to say this but _she (got up and) did a morning stretch_ seems okay too.

Comment: Praise the Sun.

Comment: Be careful with saying something like _she did her morning stretches_ -- many might assume you meant getting up out of bed and doing a series of [exercise-like stretches](http://www.calistogafitness.com/blog/2015/11/3/stretches-you-should-do-every-morning).